# Is it possible that dirty reads contain changed/unchanged data simultaneously?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I run a `UPDATE` query like:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = 1
WHERE column_name = 0
```

and another transaction run `SELECT` for the same table under `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level,

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name = 0 OR column_name = 1
```

is it possible that `SELECT` query read both updated data `1` and un-updated data `0`?

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.  And yes, you can get inconsistent data with "read uncommitted".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible that SELECT query read both updated data 1 and un-updated data 0?

Yes.  There are *no* correctness guarantees with READ UNCOMMITTED/NOLOCK.  You can get results that are just plain wrong, and never existed at any point in time, typically because the query is reading multiple data structures, eg seeking on non-clustered index, followed by a bookmark lookup on the clustered index.  The non-clustered and clustered index are not read with any consistency mechanism in READ UNCOMMITED/NOLOCK.  It's also possible that a row will move in a clustered index and be read more than once, or less than once when scanning with dirty reads.